# Pure JSP page navigation best practice?

Tags: jsp, servlets

What's the best way I can implement navigation links between various JSP pages of my Web app?

Suppose that I have a `list.jsp` that shows a list of items. Then the user clicks on one of these items to view the item in more details in `view.jsp`. Now I need a link from `view.jsp` back to `list.jsp`. However, `list.jsp` is not the only page that contains a link to `view.jsp`. For example, it is possible to go to `view.jsp`, from `search.jsp` as well. Besides that, each of `list.jsp` and `search.jsp` might have different parameters and attributes that affect the output they produce.

At the moment I have implemented this in a straightforward way using a parameter called `source` that shows the page that the user has clicked to go to the current page and by passing other parameters or attributes between the page to be remembered. However, I thought there might be a best practice for implementing this sort of functionality in a pure **JSP+Servlet** way and I wanted to ask about this before I proceed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you basically asking for breadcrumbs or for "Go Back" links?

Answer (score 1):

You should check post/redirect/get webdesign pattern it may help you to know how to create a good navigation system on your webapp and how to handle the back :)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a stack Behrang? I mean create some stack for each user in their sessions and every time he navigates to a new page, put it in the stack. Pop when he wanted to go back.

Comment: This could be troublesome if the user has two tabs for the same web site open in his browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can store from attribute which is storing page name from where you are going and put that in go back link.